# Why would an airport have a "Z" approach unless there's also a "Y" of the same type?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, procedure-design

Napa Airport (KAPC) has an ILS Z 1 approach, but no ILS Y 1. See [here](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/results/?cycle=2109&ident=apc). Why isn't this just the ILS 1? The naming rule described in the IPH, referenced [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23055/why-do-some-approaches-have-suffix-letters-such-as-y-and-z), doesn't explain why this would happen.

Comment: A reason could be Y was cancelled and Z was not renamed, this is usual. But the most probable reason is the scope for numbering is not the airport but the city. See [Why is there a "-D" circling-only approach at an airport that does not have corresponding -A, -B, and -C approaches?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/88149/3201).

Comment: mins, thanks for the link. I don't think there's any other "Napa" in California though.

Comment: Yes I realized that just a few seconds ago, but I actually found a [Y procedure](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2109/00281RY1L.PDF).

Comment: Ah, cool! How do you find historical plates? The faa search only allows current & next options. ETA: never mind. You can manually edit the URL query string to get older dates.

Comment: @mins Sounds like an answer?

Comment: @StephenS: I think at the time we considered the question was not relevant anymore since ILS Y actually existed at a time (cannot find it anymore, the link is dead).